# What is the clang toolchain?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

When I use:

```
clang test.c -o test
```

where test.c is a simple (and correct) C file. What tools Clang use to produce the executable?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the host and target systems. I use clang/LLVM to target several embedded targets from a Linux x86 host. I use GNU binutils and GDB to complete the tool chain, the NetBSD standard C library,  and QEMU to run test executables for the various targets. http://ellcc.org

By default, clang uses the host assemblers, libraries, and linkers to produce native executables. Some LLVM targets can generate object code directly and avoid using the assembler.